# how to use UTImportedTypeDeclarations in our app

Tags: ipad, file, ios5, uti

i need some help here, i want to make my app can open all file types from another app, just like Open In feature in IPAD, is it true to use `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` ?

but i dont know what to do, is there any tutorial to use it?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need UTImportedTypeDeclarations.

Here's a few tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Comment: if i want to make my app can import all file types, am i have to register all of that types in the plist?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that as I've never had to import all file types before.  :)